# High traffic spikes on certain images, serve these from Amazon S3?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, traffic, high-traffic

**First**: I'm very noob at this. Sorry. I want to learn.

My website sometimes got REALLY high traffic spikes (for certain images). (I'm at Linode btw.)

And therefore my website loading very slowly. (The cpu is low, IO rate is high). Again, not always, just *sometimes*.

So if I move these images to amazon S3 and serving from there solves the problem? So I don't need to pay more, just if I got a spike.

AND, even if my S3 storage got tens of thousands of downloads in a very short interval, it will not slow down, right?

Hope, the question was clear. Thanks very much for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could probably install varnish cache to prevent those traffic spikes from killing the server.  Varnish will cache the image in memory and relieve the load from the web server (apache, nginx, etc).

https://www.varnish-cache.org/

Comment: So I don't need S3 at all ? Varnish is enough in this case? I just need S3 if i want more **storage**?

Comment: Possibly not.  Linode has a great setup.  Its possible that you could add 128mb of ram and install varnish and it fix your issue.  But I don't know the details of your setup.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the answers, I will start reading on this way. The problem is that I have some "non-static"(cookie dependent) content, or I dont know how Varnish handles ads for example..

Answer (score 0):

s3 is designed to handle peak traffic as your example.

note s3 has a traffic charge, so you will pay more as the traffic increases.

its a good offliad from your server, but it wont remove load caused by html pages.